# Microsoft Excel Macro for seperate rows to four different columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have an excel sheet that contains names (1st row), job titles (2nd row), company/institution (3rd row), and addresses(4th row) in one big column.

I am trying to separate them into four different columns.

Please help.

Comment: What do you need? 1 -> 4 columns? 4 -> 1 column?

Comment: If just to display it differently you could use pivot tables. Or are you making this as a permanent change?

Comment: It will be a permanent change. All the data is in the 1st column and needs to be spread over 4 columns.

Comment: Could you put a sample of your data (or something that looks like it) in your question? How the elements are laid out makes a difference in how to separate them? You could either lay them out as code in the answer (indent at least 4 spaces) or put up a picture (directly or through a link to imgur.com.

Comment: And also what is your separator ?

Comment: @shA.t: For your information, "James" hasn't logged in to Super User (or any other Stack Exchange site) since Aug 20 '13 -- the day after he asked this question. This was a drive-by question, and asking him for further clarification is probably fruitless. Also, it doesn't necessarily make sense to "bump" low quality questions -- see [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286992/1672723). Injecting a clarification that we don't know to be right is especially dubious.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what you want is Copy >> Special Paste >> **Transpose**. You seem to want to switch rows to columns.

From [Mcrosoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-rows-and-columns-HP010342821.aspx):

> If data is entered in columns or rows, but you want to rearrange that
>   data into rows or columns instead, you can quickly transpose the data
>   from one to the other.
>
> For example, the regional sales data that is organized in columns
>   appears in rows after transposing the data, as shown in the following
>   graphics.
>
> [image: Regional data in columns]
>
> [image: Regional data in rows]
>
> 1 - On the worksheet, do the following:
>
> - To rearrange data from columns to rows, select the cells in the columns that contain the data.
> - To rearrange data from rows to columns, select the cells in the rows that contain the data.
>
> 2 - On the **Home** tab, in the **Clipboard** group, click **Copy**.
>
> [image: Excel Ribbon Image]
>
> **Keyboard shortcut**  To copy the selected data, you can also press
>   CTRL+C.
>
> Note   You can only use the **Copy** command to rearrange the data. To
>   complete this procedure successfully, do not use the **Cut** command.
>
> 3 - On the worksheet, select the first cell of the destination rows or columns into which you want to rearrange the copied data.
>
> **Note**   *Copy areas* and *paste areas* cannot overlap. Make sure that you
>   select a cell in a paste area that falls outside of the area from
>   which you copied the data.
>
> 4 - On the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click the arrow below **Paste**, and then click **Transpose**.
>   5 - After the data is transposed successfully, you can delete the data in the copy area.

Answer (score 2):

When I read your question, I understood it to mean that you have

[image]

and you want

[image]

Assuming your data are in Column A, starting in cell A1, set up

- `B1` – `=FIND(CHAR(10), $A1)`
- `C1` – `=FIND(CHAR(10), $A1, B1+1)`
- `D1` – `=FIND(CHAR(10), $A1, C1+1)`
- `E1` – `=LEFT($A1, B1-1)`
- `F1` – `=MID($A1, B1+1, C1-B1-1)`
- `G1` – `=MID($A1, C1+1, D1-C1-1)`
- `H1` – `=RIGHT($A1, LEN($A1)-D1)`

Then, for the example data I provided for A1, you will get the following results:

- `B1` – `13`
- `C1` – `23`
- `D1` – `32`
- `E1` – `Harold Smith`
- `F1` – `President`
- `G1` – `ABC Corp`
- `H1` – `123 Main St`

`CHAR(10)` gives an ASCII line separator character. 
Columns B, C, and D are helper columns that find the offsets (locations)
of the newlines in the data in Column A;
then Columns E through H break the data into pieces around those locations. 
Then, since you want to make a permanent change, do a copy and paste values.