# Moving numbered content from one column to another in Excel or Notepad++

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

I have a sheet that has one column with multiple rows. The rows contain numbered content (anywhere from 1-16) on individual lines - this is not a set number, it varies per row. Is there an expression that can be written to take the numbered content and put it in the following cells?

**Current layout:**

[image: Current Layout]

**Desired layout:**

[image: Desired Layout]

I can also export this as a CSV if a Notepad++ expression is necessary.

Comment: No pre-made function in Excel, but you could try the Text To Columns option (in the Data Ribbon in my Excel version), the problem is for that you need your text to have a delimiter, and your delimiter in this case is the Line Feed which is Chr(10) , and you cannot type that in the box provided, but you could use something like =SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),”,”), and then use that as  your source with proper comma delimiter so that "Text To Columns" can do its thing. Sorry but that is the easier way I can think of right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Excel Macro for seperate rows to four different columns](http://superuser.com/questions/633730/microsoft-excel-macro-for-seperate-rows-to-four-different-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exported as a csv, opened in notepad++ then found every instance of a number (exe, 1., 2, etc.) and replaced with "," and then re-uploaded to excel.

Comment: Less general, and longer than my solution... (just kidding, maybe mine was less clear)

Answer (score 0):

Copy cells from Excel to Notepad++, then make the following subs (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, by using regexes, hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd> each time):

1. `\n\r` to `\t`
2. `"\t"` to `\n`
3. `"` to *nothing*

Select all text, copy, go back to Excel, select 1st cell of your area, paste.